# Filtering multiple columns of data frame inside a loop in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I want to use a loop to filter multiple columns of a data frame, removing rows where any of the given column values are in a particular list.

For instance:

```
> my_df <- data.frame(word1 = c("one", "two", "red", "blue"), word2 = c("apple","orange","banana","pear"), word3 = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green"))
> color_words = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue")
> my_df
  word1  word2  word3
1   one  apple    red
2   two orange orange
3   red banana yellow
4  blue   pear  green
```

Using the dplyr `filter()` function:

```
> my_df %>% filter(!word1 %in% color_words) %>% filter(!word2 %in% color_words)
  word1 word2 word3
1   one apple   red
```

My first attempt to perform this filtering in a loop was:

```
col_names <- c("word1","word2")
for(col in col_names){
    my_df <- my_df %>% filter(!col %in% color_words)
}
> my_df
  word1  word2  word3
1   one  apple    red
2   two orange orange
3   red banana yellow
4  blue   pear  green
```

I read about [quoting and unquoting](https://tidyeval.tidyverse.org/dplyr.html#enquo-and---quote-and-unquote-arguments) when using `filter()`, so I also tried:

```
for(col in col_names){
    col <- enquo(col)
    my_df <- my_df %>% filter(!UQ(col) %in% color_words)
}
> my_df
  word1  word2  word3
1   one  apple    red
2   two orange orange
3   red banana yellow
4  blue   pear  green
```

and

```
for(col in col_names){
    my_df <- my_df %>% filter(!UQ(col) %in% color_words)
}
> my_df
  word1  word2  word3
1   one  apple    red
2   two orange orange
3   red banana yellow
4  blue   pear  green
```

What is the correct way to go about doing this filtering via a loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a loop you can use `filter` with `across` to apply a function for multiple columns

```
library(dplyr)
my_df %>% filter(across(all_of(col_names), ~!. %in% color_words))

#  word1 word2 word3
#1   one apple   red
```

If you have an older version of `dplyr`, use `filter_at` :

```
my_df %>% filter_at(col_names, all_vars(!. %in% color_words))
```

Comment: Sorry, it was not clear from my question, but in general I do not want to filter *all* of the columns, only the columns in a particular list (in this case `col_names`).

Comment: Thank you. I'm still curious why none of my attempts to use a loop worked?

Answer (score 0):

use `base`

```r
my_df <- data.frame(word1 = c("one", "two", "red", "blue"), word2 = c("apple","orange","banana","pear"), word3 = c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green"))
color_words <-  paste0(c("red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "blue"), collapse = "|") 
fltr <- apply(my_df[1:2], 1, function(x) !any(grepl(color_words, x)))
my_df[fltr, ]
#>   word1 word2 word3
#> 1   one apple   red
```

<sup>Created on 2020-09-25 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>